# c: string input with strut and array

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct

I am working on a program, that when the user enters the month and day number, the month and number of days year to date prints out. Expected input and out put are below.

```
Enter month and day number?  december 30
December (DEC) 31 means 364 days YTD.
```

My program does compile, I am using microsoft visual studio.Using the same input as in the expected input I attempt to run the program; however, after I enter the month and day number the program crashes.

Warnings from the compiler:

```
'scanf_s' : format string '%s' requires an argument of type 'unsigned int', but variadic argument 2 has type 'int *'    

'scanf_s' : not enough arguments passed for format string
```

When I use the debugger, the program gives these message after I enter the month and day and then proceed to step through the code. It appears that does not have enough memory to continue? If this is the problem what is the most logical way to fix it?

```
Exception thrown at 0x0FCA0BA9 (ucrtbased.dll) in lab14program345words.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x003C0000.
```

Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int finddata(int month, int days);

struct month
{
    char name[10];
    char abbrev[4];
    int days;
    int monumb;
};



int main()
{
    struct month months[12] =
    {
        { "January", "jan", 31, 1 },
        { "February", "feb", 28, 2 },
        { "March", "mar", 31, 3 },
        { "April", "apr", 30, 4 },
        { "May", "may", 31, 5 },
        { "June", "jun", 30, 6 },
        { "July", "jul", 31, 7 },
        { "August", "aug", 31, 8 },
        { "September", "sep", 30, 9 },
        { "October", "oct", 31, 10 },
        { "November", "nov", 30, 11 },
        { "December", "dec", 31, 12 }
    };
    struct month userdata;
    int i = 0;
    int total;

    do
    {
        printf("Enter month and day number:");

        scanf_s("%s %d", userdata.name, &userdata.days); //line 42, where the warnings occur

        toupper(userdata.name[0]);

        if (strcmp(userdata.name, months[i].name) == 0) // should compare user's entered month to months in month montths array
        {
            puts(months[i].name);
            puts(months[i].abbrev);
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }


        total = finddata(months[i].monumb, userdata.days); // should pass the month number and days the user entered. 
        printf("%d days YTD.\n", total);

    } while ((userdata.monumb > 0) || (userdata.monumb < 13));


    return 0;
}



int finddata(int months, int days)
{
    int total = 0;

    if (months == 1)
    {
        total = days;
    }
    else if (months == 2)
    {
        total = days + 31;
    }
    else if (months == 3)
    {
        total = 31 + 28 + days;
    }
    else if (months == 4)
    {
        total = 31 + 28 + 31 + days;
    }
    else if (months == 5)
    {
        total = 31 + 28 + 31 + 30 + days;
    }
    else if (months == 6)
    {
        total = 31 + 28 + 31 + 30 + 31 + days;
    }
    else if (months == 7)
    {
        total = (31 * 3) + 28 + (30 * 2) + days;
    }
    else if (months == 8)
    {
        total = (31 * 4) + 28 + (30 * 2) + days;
    }
    else if (months == 9)
    {
        total = (31 * 5) + 28 + (30 * 2) + days;
    }
    else if (months == 10)
    {
        total = (31 * 5) + 28 + (30 * 3) + days;
    }
    else if (months == 11)
    {
        total = (31 * 6) + 28 + (30 * 3) + days;
    }
    else if (months == 12)
    {
        total = (31 * 6) + 28 + (30 * 4) + days;
    }
    else
    {
        //blank
    }



    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf_s("%s %d", userdata.name, &userdata.days);
```

If you read about [`scanf_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx), it requires to pass another parameter with `%s` and `%c` which represents length.

So in your case you need to do is -

```
scanf_s("%s %d", userdata.name, (rsize_t)sizeof userdata.name, &userdata.days);
```

You get warning because `&userdata.days` is considered as the length parameter and there is a type mismatch. 
In case of `%c` you need to pass `1` to read one character.

Comment: "In case of %c you need to pass 1" --> does not it need to be `(rsize_t)1` just like `(rsize_t)sizeof userdata.name`.  OTOH if `1` is OK, then  `(unsigned)sizeof userdata.name` should be OK.  The type requirements are certainly the same for the size parameters of `"%s"` and `"%c"`.  I suspect the linked ref and the C spec slightly differ on this point.